# Creating a RDF file using JAVA

Tags: java, rdf

I am writing a program using Netbeans to create a RDF file. It is getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.*;

public class RDFWriter extends Object
    {
     public static void main (String args[])
     {
        String personURI    = "http://localhost/hrudya";
        String givenName    = "GOPIKA";
        String familyName   = "NG";
        String fullName     = givenName + " " + familyName;
        String course1 = "http://localhost/relationship/";
        try {
            // create an empty model
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
          // create the resource  and add the properties cascading style
        Resource hrudya = model.createResource(personURI);
        Property course = model.createProperty(course1,"course");
        hrudya.addProperty( VCARD.FN, fullName);
        hrudya.addProperty( VCARD.Given, givenName);
        hrudya.addProperty( DC.title, "SEMANTIC WEB");
        hrudya.addProperty(course,"M.Tech_CSE");
        //model.write(new PrintWriter(System.out));
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("p2cse10009/Desktop/rr.rdf");
        model.write(fout);

        FileOutputStream fout1=new FileOutputStream("p2cse10009/Desktop/hr.xml");
        model.write(fout1);
      }
       catch (Exception e)
         {
            System.out.println("Failed: " + e);
         }
    }

    public RDFWriter() {
    }
}
```

Which library should I add?

Comment: Are you using Maven for you dependcy management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dependencies listed in the POM of Jena. See http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/hp/hpl/jena/jena/2.6.4/jena-2.6.4.pom

Answer (score 1):

Probably http://www.slf4j.org/

Answer (score 1):

> Which library should I add?

You should add the `slf4j` library and a binding library to make it use the *actual* logging library of your choice.

I recommend that you read the [SLF4J User Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).